# Typescript narrow {[key: string]: T} to an object literal

Tags: typescript

I would like to write a function that enforces an object to be of type {[key: string]: T} and returns an object literal of the provided argument.

For example, if I have the following type A:

```
interface A{
  a: string,
  b: number
}
```

I would like to have a function `B` that takes an object with properties, all of type `A`, and returns the provided object with properties accessible using dot notation.

My current function is this:

```
const B = (arg: {[key: string]: A}) => arg;
```

But when I call it like so:

```
const c = B({
  a: {
    a: "test",
    b: 1
  }
})
```

I can't access the property `a` with dot notation, like `c.a`.

How can I make it so that function B returns a literal type based on what it receives so that I can access properties with dot notation?

Comment: Why is `B` needed at all?

Comment: It's for a library, so it will allow JS autocompletion and type checking for my specific use case.

Comment: But what does the function `B` actually do that can't be achieved by just not using it? If you write `const c = {a: {a: "test", b: 1}}` then you can write `c.a` and get autocompletion suggestions.

Comment: Yes, but I want to enforce that `c` follows the pattern `{[key: string]: A}` when it's created. By passing it through the function, a non-Typescript user will get autocompletion and warnings when CREATING the variable. Perhaps I should update my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

[Typescript rpl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIG8BQzlwFzIDOYUoA5gDTbIBGBIArgLY3SYC%20mmCA9iMcgBCyALzIAPABVkEAB6QQAE0LIAShF5RF44qRCU0APkMAKOFDIFJASiujDuCwG4uvfmGQJRQk1hz5kPxxcAgAiSGJQqmDaAgBGak52a1c%20Qh4AGwgAOgyeMhMEbLhi6yA)

```
interface A{
  a: string,
  b: number
}

const B = <T extends Record<string, A>>(arg: T): T => arg;

const c = B({
  a: {
    a: "test",
    b: 1
  }
})

console.log(c.a.a)
```

Comment: I figured it was generics, and I actually tried using Record, but apparently I was using it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this works the same if you write `{[k: string]: A}` instead of `Record<string, A>` - those are equivalent.